# SublimeText 3 Anaconda autocomplete bug

Tags: python-3.x, autocomplete, sublimetext3

I'm new to SublimeText and Python3, so I don't really know how to turn Sublime autocomplete on. I installed Anaconda from Package Control, but I don't know how to use it. Some autocomplete shows up, but I don't think it's Anaconda's. That autocomplete keeps on poping up, then dissapearing. I can't read what it says and it hurts my eyes. How can i properly set up the autocomplete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in case you are still looking for the answer, I had a similar problem. I had both SublimeJEDI autocompletion as well as Anaconda. 
The flashing behavior is a result of you having two separate autocompletes fighting for the same space.

Turning off SublimeJEDI solved this for me - I couldn't find a way to turn off Anaconda's.